# Duplicate Line Filter Not Working

Tags: java, file

I have this code which I have reviewed many times. It seems to filter a lot, but some duplicates get through?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class ipstoblockfilter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("E:\\alp\\ipstoblock.txt");

       try {

           Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

 try
    {
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("E:\\alp\\ipstoblockfiltered.txt");
           while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
               String nextLine = sc.nextLine();

               Scanner nextLineParser = new Scanner(nextLine);

               // check if duplicate
                       File filefiltered = new File("E:\\alp\\ipstoblockfiltered.txt");

       try {

           Scanner scff = new Scanner(filefiltered);
           List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
           while (scff.hasNextLine())  {
           arrayList.add(scff.nextLine());
           } //While


     if (!arrayList.contains(nextLine)) {
     printWriter.println(nextLine);
     }

           } //duptry

                  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           } //dupcatch


               // check if duplicate



           } //while
           printWriter.close();
           }
               catch (FileNotFoundException ex)  
    {

           }
           sc.close();
       } 
       catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

    } //Main
} // Class
```

How is this possible?

Please let me know if there is anything I should look into or change!

Thank you for the help!

EDIT:

So I tried andrewdleach's code, and is is producing the following errors

[error]

```
ipstoblockfilter.java:7: error: incompatible types: File cannot be converted to Reader
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
                                           ^
ipstoblockfilter.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
Printwriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
^
  symbol:   class Printwriter
  location: class ipstoblockcommands
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
2 errors
```

[/error]

Here is the code of his that I tried
[code]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class ipstoblockcommands {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

File file = new File("E:\\alp\\ipstoblock.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
Set<String> lineSet= new HashSet<>();

while (reader.readLine() != null) {
    lineSet.add(reader.readLine().trim());
}

reader.close();
Printwriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);

Iterator<String> iterator = lineSet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    writer.write(iterator.next());
}

writer.close();


    } //Main


} // Class
```

[/code]

Comment: Wouldn't let me post without more body text, I have now added such text.

Comment: Are you just comparing lines for equality and removing if they are equal?

Comment: So I have a list of ips in ipstoblock.txt, I want to save all the unique ips in ipstoblockfiltered.txt so what I tried to do in the code is for each line of ipstoblock.txt I would check every line of the filtered file for a match. If there is no match then add the new unique ip.

Comment: You are creating but not using the `nextLineParser` object, why?

Comment: can you also post ipstoblock.txt here too ? At least a sample file.

Comment: " 
You are creating but not using the nextLineParser object, why? –  Alexandro Sifuentes Díaz 1 min ago"

I don't think that's a valid objcet. I use nextLine() and hasNextLine() frequently in the code though

Comment: "can you also post ipstoblock.txt here too ? At least a sample file. –  Alp 2 mins ago"

1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3

Comment: Reading from a file during a write loop to the same file is highly unrecommended. Just keep the strings in memory, in a set or something.

Comment: RealSkeptic, thank you for the advice could you provide some code example please?

Answer (score 1):

From the code, you are parsing one line at a time and writing with the PrintWriter if the Arraylist does not contain your line. Good.

However, you are trying to simultaneously read and print from/to the same file.

Instead, read every line into a data structure of Strings, remove duplicates and then write back out to the file after sorting and parsing all the appropriate data.

EDIT:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class IpScanner {

public IpScanner() {

} 

private void start() {
    try {
        File file = new File("FILE_PATH\\ipstoblock.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        Set<String> lineSet= new HashSet<>();

        while (reader.readLine() != null) {
            lineSet.add(reader.readLine().trim());
        }

        reader.close();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);

        Iterator<String> iterator = lineSet.iterator();
           while (iterator.hasNext()) {
               writer.write(iterator.next() + "\r\n");
        }

        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't parse");
    }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new IpScanner().start();
   } 
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of this? Thank you for the help

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be giving me some errors, I updated the OP

Comment: Forgot to put a FileReader object inside the BufferedReader constructor. My code may or may not be syntactically correct.

Comment: If it solved your problem please mark as resolved by clicking the opaque check mark next to the question.

Comment: Will do once I fix the code, what you posted doesn't work.

Comment: Without seeing the exact text file it's hard to know what will and will not work.

Comment: It's just a list of IPs

Comment: I compiled and tested the above code myself. It works. However, I suggest you attempt at rewriting to understand the concepts.

Comment: That will happen if your file to parse is not in the same directory as your executable. Maybe do a little more studying on Java File I/O before asking someone else to write your code for you.

Comment: I even put the file into the same directory as the .java and .class and changed it to  File file = new File("ipstoblock.txt"); as well as full path